# Set a cron every 10 days starting from 16th January

Tags: linux, unix, cron, cron-task

How to set a cron to execute every `10 days` starting from `16th January`? Would this suffice?

```
30 7 16-15/10 * * command >/dev/null
```

The above starts at `7.30 AM`, `16th of every month` and ends on `next month 15th` and repeats every `10 days`. I don't think what I have above is correct. Can anyone tell me how to set up the cron so that month ends are taken into account and every `10 days` the command is executed starting from `16th January this year 2016`?.

Comment: cron really isn't equipped to handle that logic.  You're better off running a wrapper script every day that checks the date and aborts or continues as appropriate.

Comment: @WilliamPursell  Searched a lot and realized it could'ntt.. I have written something that will suffice for date range starting from January 6th 2016 to December 31st 2016. I wrote 7 cron commands.  

30 7 6,16,26 1,3 * command >/dev/null

30 7 5,15,25 2,4,5 * command >/dev/null 

30 7 4,14,24 6,7 * command >/dev/null 

30 7 3,13,23 8 * command >/dev/null

30 7 2,12,22 9,10 * command >/dev/null 

30 7 1,11,21 11,12 * command >/dev/null 

30 7 31 12 * command >/dev/null

2016 is a leap year also. I know this is ridiculous but I am new and need help writing a script. I will change it next year.

Comment: Do you want it to run on January 16 next year, or every 10 days indefinitely?

Comment: @KeithThompson every 10 days indefinitely. Starting from January 16 2016.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As William suggested, cron can't handle this complexity by itself.  However, you can run a cron job more frequently, and use something else for the logic.  For example;

```
30 7 16-31 1 * date '+\%j' | grep -q '0$' && yourcommand
30 7 *  2-12 * date '+\%j' | grep -q '0$' && yourcommand
```

This date format string prints the day of the year, from 001 to 365. The `grep -q` will do a pattern match, NOT print the results, but return a success of a failure on the basis of what it finds. Every 10 days, the day of the year ends in a zero.  On those days, `yourcommand` gets run.

This has a problem with the year roll-over. A more complex alternative might be to do a similar grep on a product of `date '+%s'` (the epoch second), but you'll need to do math to turn seconds into days for analysis by `grep`. This might work (you should test):

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

30 7 * * * echo $(( $(date '+%s') / 86400 )) | grep '0$' && yourcommand
```

(Add your Jan 16th logic too, of course.)

This relies on the fact that shell arithmetic can only handle integers.  The shell simply truncates rather than rounding.

---

**UPDATE**

In a comment on another answer, you clarified your requirements:

> The command should start executing on January 16th, and continue like on January 26th, February 5th, February 15th and so on – jai

For this, the epoch-second approach is probably the right direction.

```
% date -v1m -v16d -v7H -v30M -v0S '+%s'
1452947400
```

(I'm in FreeBSD, hence these arguments to `date`.)

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

30 7 * * * [[ $(( ($(date '+\%s') - 1452947400) \% 864000 )) == 0 ]] && yourcommand
```

This expression subtracts the epoch second of 7:30AM Jan 16 (my timezone) from the current time, and tests whether the resultant difference is divisible by 10 days.  If it is, the expression evaluates true and yourcommand is run.  Note that `$(( 0 % $x ))` evaluates to 0 for any value of $x.

This may be prone to error if cron is particularly busy and can't get to your job in the one second where the math works out.

If you want to make this any more complex (and perhaps even if it's *this* complex), I recommend you move the logic into a separate shell script to handle the date comparison math.  Especially if you plan to add a fudge factor to allow for jobs to miss their 1-second window .. that would likely be multiple lines of script, which is awkward to maintain in a single cronjob entry.

Comment: Actually my full cron could be something like this

30 7 * * * php command emailid $(date "+\%D")

command is a laravel command that takes the date and email as parameters and generates report for the transactions of previous 10 days. I had not mentioned that earlier. If current date is 16th January 2016 then if the cron is executed the command generates report for all transactions betwn 6th & 15th. If I could execute the command every day and check if difference in number of days between the date parameter and 6th January 2016 is a multiple of 10 then generate report otherwise just return.

Answer (score 0):

```
0 30 7 1/10 * ? * command >/dev/null
```

Output for the above express is,

```
Saturday, January 16, 2016 7:30 AM 
    1.  Thursday, January 21, 2016 7:30 AM
    2.  Sunday, January 31, 2016 7:30 AM
    3.  Monday, February 1, 2016 7:30 AM
    4.  Thursday, February 11, 2016 7:30 AM
    5.  Sunday, February 21, 2016 7:30 AM
```

Output for your expression

```
i.e 30 7 16-15/10 * * command >/dev/null

    2016-01-15 07:30:00
    2016-02-15 07:30:00
    2016-03-15 07:30:00
    2016-04-15 07:30:00
    2016-05-15 07:30:00
    2016-06-15 07:30:00
    2016-07-15 07:30:00
    2016-08-15 07:30:00
    2016-09-15 07:30:00
    2016-10-15 07:30:00
```

The closest syntax would like this:

```
30 7 1-30/10 * *
30 7 1-31/10 * *
30 7 1-28/10 * *
30 7 1-29/10 * *
```

You can test the cron expression here http://cron.schlitt.info/

Comment: The command should start executing on January 16th, and continue like on January 26th, February 5th, February 15th and so on

Answer (score 0):

**Observation**: the math capabilities of cron are next to non-existent. The math capabilities of the Unix tools are endless.

**Conclusion**: move the problem from the cron domain to the shell domain.

**Solution**: run this each day with `30 7 * * * /path/to/script` in the crontab:

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=$(/usr/bin/getconf PATH)
if test $(($(date +%j) % 10)) = 6; then
    your_command
fi
```

This tests whether the day-of-year modulo 10 is 6, like it is for January 16 (and January 6th is already in the past...).

**Thinking outside the box:**
Fix your requirement. Convince whoever came up with that funny 10 day cycle to accept a 7 day cycle. So much easier for cron. This is following the KISS principle.

Comment: Actually my full cron could be something like this 

30 7 * * * php command emailid $(date "+\%D")

Command is a laravel command that takes the date and email as parameters and generates a report for the transactions of previous 10 days. I had not mentioned that earlier. If current date is 16th January 2016 then if the cron is executed the command generates report for all transactions betwn 6th & 15th. If I could execute the command every day and check if difference in number of days between the date parameter and 6th January 2016 is a multiple of 10 then generate report otherwise just return.